# rendering vue.js components and passing in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having trouble figuring out how to render a parent component, display a list of contracts in a list on part of the page, and when a user clicks on one of them, display the details of that specific contract on the other part of the page.

Here is my slim file:

```
#contracts_area
  .filter-section
     ul
       li.filter-item v-for="contract in contractsAry" :key="contract.id" @click="showContract(contract)"
        | {{ contract.name }}
  .display-section
    component :is="currentView" transition="fade" transition-mode="out-in"

script type="text/x-template" id="manage-contracts-template"
  div
    h1 Blank when page is newly loaded for now

script type="text/x-template" id="view-contract-template"
  div :apply_contract="showContract"
    h1#display-item__name v-name="name"
```

javascript:

```
Vue.component('manage-template', {
    template: '#manage-contracts-template'
  });

  Vue.component('view-contract', {
    template: '#view-contract-template',
    props: ['show_contract'],
    data: function() {
      return {
        name: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      showContract: function(contract) {
        return this.name = contract.name
      }
    }
  });

  Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  var contractsResource = Vue.resource('/all_contracts{/id}.json');

  var contracts = new Vue({
    el: '#contracts_area',
    data: {
      currentView: 'manage-template',
      contractsAry: [],
      errors: {}
    },
    mounted: function() {
      var that = this;
      contractsResource.get().then(
        function(res) {
          that.contractsAry = res.data;
        }
      )
    },
    methods: {
      showContract: function(contract) {
        this.currentView = 'view-contract'
      }
    }
  });
```

Basically I'd like it so that when a user clicks on any contract item in the .filter-section, it shows the data for that contract in the .display-section. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you can bind a value to a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

```
.display-section
  component :is="currentView" :contract="currentContract"
```

view-contract

```
props: ['contract']
```

contracts-area

```
data: {
  currentContract: null,
},
methods: {
  showContract: function(contract) {
    this.currentView = "view-contract";
    this.currentContract = contract;
  }
}
```

---

There are multiple ways to pass data in Vue.

1. Binding values to [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).
2. Using [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs) to directly call a method from a child component.
3. [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events). Note that to pass events globally, you will need a global event bus.
4. A single central source of truth (i.e. [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html))

I have illustrated methods 1, 2, 3 in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/c6p/pen/dVORWW?editors=1011#code-area)

Note that **2**nd and **3**rd methods will only work after your component has been rendered. In your case, since your components for currentView are dynamic and when user clicked, display-section component does not yet exists; it will not receive any events yet. So their content will be empty at first.

To workaround this you can directly access `$parent` in `mounted()` from child component, however this would create coupling between them. Another solution is creating the components but [conditionally displaying](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) them. And one another solution would be waiting until child component has been mounted and then emitting events.

If your needs are simple I suggest binding values to props (**1**), else you may consider using something like vuex.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for your help! And thank you for the in-depth answer, huge help for me as I'm just starting out with Vue.